# Adding more than one relationship to a Laravel factory method results in TypeError

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Adding a single relationship to a Factory method works, but when I add a second relationship I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::applyStates() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php on line 278

### SiteFactory.php

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use App\District;
use App\Contact;

$factory->define(App\Site::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $name = ucfirst($faker->word());
    if (strlen($name) > 10)
    {
        $name = substr($name, 0, 10);
    }

    $types = [
        'Elementary School' => 'Elem',
        'High School' => 'HS',
        'Junior High' => 'Jr. High'
    ];

    $type = array_rand($types);

    return [
        'name' => $name.' '.$type,
        'shortname' => $name.' '.$types[$type],
        'tinyname' => $name,
        'district_id' => function() {
            return factory(District::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'contact_id' => function() {
            return factory(Contact::class)->create()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

### ContactFactory.php

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Contact::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    //
});
```

### StackTrace

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::applyStates() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php on line 278

/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:312
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:278
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:292
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:116
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:300
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:219
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:178
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/database/factories/SiteFactory.php:22
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:274
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:292
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php:122
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:300
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:219
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:178
/home/vagrant/code/rtl/tests/Unit/SiteUnitTest.php:21
```

### Site.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\District;
use App\Series;
use App\Address;
use App\Contact;

class Site extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function district()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(District::class);
    }

    public function series()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Series::class);
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class);
    }
}
```

### Contact.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong? I read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#using-factories), I see the section regarding applying states, but that doesn't seem to apply to this code.

I should also note, that I'm trying a go at test driven development (TDD) for the first time (which is why the Contact model is incomplete). Also, I've tried the Contact relationship both ways (BelongsTo and HasOne), as I'm still working on how that will ultimately work out, since a contact can belong to different tables.

Comment: Can you show your models, please?

Comment: @aynber Models added. Thanks!

Comment: `'contact_id' => $contact->id,
        'contact_id' => function() {
            return factory(Contact::class)->create()->id;
        },` why do you have 2 `contact_id` key?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din Residual code from testing other ways of tying to make it work. Removed the extra line (and edited the attached code) and receive the same error

Comment: does `factory(Contact::class)->create()->id;`  and  `factory(District::class)->create()->id` works as expected and are their relations correct?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din *sigh* You nailed it! My ContactFactory was empty adding `return [];` to the ContactFactory.php file fixed the problem. I originally tested both and I tested just The DistrictFactory, it didn't even cross my mind to only the ContactFactory. Thank you for this valuable lesson!

Comment: ^^ glad it works. BTW pay attention to one-to-one relation

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din I've updated the question to show the contact factory. If you could point that out as an answer, it might help someone else who makes this silly mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `factory(Contact::class)->create()->id;` and `factory(District::class)->create()->id`, so you have to make sure they both work correctly.

As we see after the last update in the question, you are missing the code in `ContactFactory.php`.

so that is the point!

P.S. these kinds of errors may arise due to TDD (Test Driven Development).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you again. First time using a framework and sometimes you get so caught up in trying to remember how to do things within the framework your lose sight of the simple things like testing your code properly :)

Comment: yea, that's true ^^. Good luck!